# trim the decimal value with only numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have few fields in my tables with `V1.5`, `1.6`, `V1.6.7`. I want to remove all the characters and retain only numbers in the table.

- `V1.5` should change to `1.5`
- `V1.6.7` should change to `1.6.7`
- `1.6` should be as it as.

Comment: Do you want to permanently change them or just display them that way on a query? Check the PostgresQL documentation for string processing functions.

Comment: I want to permanently change them. update all such values in the column

Comment: Just use the Postgresql string functions (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) with UPDATE. You can use `regex_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove everything that is not a digit or dot, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g')
```

e.g.

```
with data (version) as (
  values 
    ('V1.5'),
    ('V1.6.7'),
    ('1.2.3'),
    ('3.4.5-alpha')
)
select version, regexp_replace(version, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g') as clean_version
from data;
```

returns:

```
version     | clean_version
------------+--------------
V1.5        | 1.5          
V1.6.7      | 1.6.7        
1.2.3       | 1.2.3        
3.4.5-alpha | 3.4.5
```

To change the data in your table, use an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g')
where the_column <> regexp_replace(the_column, '[^0-9.]', '', 'g');
```

The `where` clause prevents updates that don't change anything.

Of course, you need to replace `the_column` with your real column name that you want to change.